# How to activate multiple Processes in SimPy

Tags: simpy

I want to create two kinds of Processes, they are basically two patient types, One Category1 and other is Catergory2. Each of these are generated at a specific interval i.e. the rate of arriving at Emergency Room and each of them are competing for resources, which are doctors such. I don't know how to create two different processes. The terminal output is such

```
 4.4910 Patient_C304: Here I am. [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 4.4910 Patient_C304: Waited  0.000
 5.0008 Patient_C304: Finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/o/Documents/hos/bank.py", line 153, in <module>
    simulate(until=maxTime)
  File "/home/o/Documents/hos/hos/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SimPy/Globals.py", line 59, in simulate
    return sim.simulate(until = until)
  File "/home/o/Documents/hos/hos/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SimPy/Simulation.py", line 551, in simulate
    step()
  File "/home/o/Documents/hos/hos/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SimPy/Simulation.py", line 495, in step
    resultTuple = next(proc._nextpoint)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator
```

Heres my code:

```
""" Hospital10: Several doctors with individual queues"""
from SimPy.Simulation import *
from random import expovariate, triangular, seed

# Model components ------------------------

interval_c = [0.02, 0.07, 0.12]
class Source(Process):
    """ Source generates Patients randomly"""

    def generate_C1(self, number, interval, doctors):
        for i in range(number):

            p_C1 = PatientC1(name="Patient_C1%02d" % (i,))
            activate(p_C1, p_C1.visit(doctors))
            t_C1 = expovariate(interval[0])
            yield hold, self, t_C1, 

    def generate_C2(self, number, interval, doctors):
        for i in range(number):
             p_C2 = PatientC2(name="Patient_C2%02d" % (i,))
             activate(p_C2, p_C2.visit(doctors))
             t_C2 = expovariate(interval[1])
             yield hold, self, t_C2

    def generate_C3( self, number, interval, doctors):
        for i in range(number):
             p_C3= PatientC3(name="Patient_C3%02d" % (i,))
             activate(p_C3, p_C3.visit(doctors))
             t_C3 = expovariate(interval[2])
             yield hold, self, t_C3
             
            





def NoInSystem(R):
    """ Total number of Patients in the resource R"""
    return (len(R.waitQ)+len(R.activeQ))


class PatientC1(Process):
    """ Patient arrives, chooses the shortest queue
        is served and leaves
    """

        

    def visit(self, doctors):
        arrive = now()
        Qlength = [NoInSystem(doctors[i]) for i in range(Nd)]
        print("%7.4f %s: Here I am. %s" % (now(), self.name, Qlength))
        for i in range(Nd):
            if Qlength[i] == 0 or Qlength[i] == min(Qlength):
                choice = i  # the chosen queue number
                break

        yield request, self, doctors[choice]
        wait = now()-arrive
        print("%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f" % (now(), self.name, wait))
        tib = triangular(1.0/timeInHospital)
        yield hold, self, tib
        yield release, self, doctors[choice]

        print("%7.4f %s: Finished" % (now(), self.name))

# Experiment data -------------------------
class PatientC2(Process):
    """ Patient arrives, chooses the shortest queue
        is served and leaves
    """


    def visit(self, doctors):
        arrive = now()
        Qlength = [NoInSystem(doctors[i]) for i in range(Nd)]
        print("%7.4f %s: Here I am. %s" % (now(), self.name, Qlength))
        for i in range(Nd):
            if Qlength[i] == 0 or Qlength[i] == min(Qlength):
                choice = i  # the chosen queue number
                break

        yield request, self, doctors[choice]
        wait = now()-arrive
        print("%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f" % (now(), self.name, wait))
        tib = triangular(1.0/timeInHospital)
        yield hold, self, tib
        yield release, self, doctors[choice]

        print("%7.4f %s: Finished" % (now(), self.name))



class PatientC3(Process):
    """ Patient arrives, chooses the shortest queue
        is served and leaves
    """


    def visit(self, doctors):
        arrive = now()
        Qlength = [NoInSystem(doctors[i]) for i in range(Nd)]
        print("%7.4f %s: Here I am. %s" % (now(), self.name, Qlength))
        for i in range(Nd):
            if Qlength[i] == 0 or Qlength[i] == min(Qlength):
                choice = i  # the chosen queue number
                break

        yield request, self, doctors[choice]
        wait = now()-arrive
        print("%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f" % (now(), self.name, wait))
        tib = triangular(1.0/timeInHospital)
        yield hold, self, tib
        yield release, self, doctors[choice]

        print("%7.4f %s: Finished" % (now(), self.name))













maxNumber = 5
maxTime = 400.0  # minutes
timeInHospital = 12.0  # mean, minutes
ARRint = 0.02  # mean, minutes
Nd = 5          # number of doctors
theseed = 12345

# Model/Experiment ------------------------------

seed(theseed)
# kk = [Resource(name="Doctor1"), Resource(name="Doctor2")]
kk = [Resource(name="Doctor1"), Resource(name="Doctor2"), Resource(name="Doctor3"), Resource(name="Doctor4"), Resource(name="Doctor5")]
initialize()
s = Source('Source')
activate(s, s.generate_C1(number=maxNumber, interval=interval_c,
                       doctors=kk), at=0.0)
activate(s, s.generate_C2(number=maxNumber, interval=interval_c,
                       doctors=kk), at=0.0)

activate(s, s.generate_C3(number=maxNumber, interval=interval_c,
                       doctors=kk), at=0.0)
simulate(until=maxTime)
```

Comment: I cannot look at this till next week, but...   Don't make your classes decedents of Process.  A process is just a method with a yield <event> in it and the most often used event is env.timeout(<some num>).  use env = Environment() and env.process(<your generator process>) to start process.  Look at the gas station example in the docs.  You are right that if you want each resource to have its own queue then it needs to be its own resource pool with one resource.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait. But for now I created objects of each class and then activated them individually, and then added a Hold for all of them at the end.
```
p_C1 = PatientC1(name="Patient_C1%02d" % (i,))
            activate(p_C1, p_C1.visit(doctors, ReSusRooms))
            t_C1 = expovariate(interval[0])

            p_C2 = PatientC2(name="Patient_C2%02d" % (i,))
            activate(p_C2, p_C2.visit(doctors, nurses, beds))
            t_C2 = expovariate(interval[1])

```

Answer (score 1):

This focuses on selecting a short queue and generating visits

```
"""
quick sim of pataints visting doctors

programmer Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random
import sys
from typing import Tuple

def get_short(resourceDict) -> Tuple[str, simpy.Resource]:
    """
    finds the resource in a dict with the shortest queue + users

    returns doc's name, and resource
    """
    best_q_len = sys.maxsize
    best_r = None
    best_k = None

    # iter though dict comparing queue lenghts
    for k,v in resourceDict.items():
        q_len = len(v.users) + len(v.queue)
        if q_len < best_q_len:
            best_q_len = q_len
            best_r = v
            best_k = k

    return best_k, best_r

def visit(env, id, pat_type, doc_dict):
    """
    sims a patient meeting with a doc

    queue
    met
    leave
    """

    # select doc with shortest queue
    doc, r = get_short(doc_dict)

    q_len = len(r.users) + len(r.queue)
    print(f'{env.now} - patient {id} of type {pat_type} has queued with doc {doc} queue size {q_len}')

    with r.request() as req:
        # wait in queue
        yield req
        
        # visit with doc
        print(f'{env.now} - patient {id} of type {pat_type} is with doc {doc}')
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(2,10))

        # leave
        print(f'{env.now} - patient {id} of type {pat_type} is done with doc {doc}')

next_id = 1

def gen_visits(env, pat_type, doc_dict):
    """
    gen a stream of patients of pat_type
    """

    global next_id
    
    while True:
        # wait for next arrival
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(1,4))

        #start visit
        env.process(visit(env, 'pat_' + str(next_id), pat_type, doc_dict))
        next_id += 1

# start sim

env = simpy.Environment()

# to create a queue for each doc, make each doc its own resource of cap=1
doc_dict = {'doc_' + str(i): simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1) for i in range(1,4+1)}

# gen different types of pataients
env.process(gen_visits(env, "pat_type_A", doc_dict))
env.process(gen_visits(env, "pat_type_B", doc_dict))

env.run(100)
```